# Client Program on PC connect to Server program on Android

Tags: java, android

I am Trying to Make A simple Server App  and Client program in order to extend

their  Work in later time to use them in my Graduation Project

I have the Client Code as Java simple Program On my PC

and I have an Android Thread in Which i Put my Server  programm on android phone

the server should listen to  ports

and register them on Accept

the problem is that when i Run The Emulator and when i use local Address "127.0.0.1"

on both Client and Server First i start server and it launches the thread succefullt

but when run the Client Programm it catches "Connection Refused Exception "

when i build the APK and launch the server from my Android Phone on ip "192.168.3.100" the server start successfully

The client also runs correctly ,but when i send any number nothing shows up in my android activity

any advice would be very much appreciated

My Server Code

```
          package com.example.laptophome.securesys;

/**
  * Created by laptop home on 13-Apr-17.
  */
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Connection extends Thread {

    private boolean isBinded = false;
    private String IpAddress;
    private Context cx;
    private int num;
    //private Socket socket;
    private InputStreamReader inRead;
    public ServerSocketChannel server;
   // private volatile  boolean isRunning =true;
        public Connection(String IpAddress ,Context cx) {
        this.IpAddress = IpAddress;
        this.cx = cx;

       }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            Selector selector = Selector.open();


            int[] ports = {5050, 4001, 6000};
         for (int port : ports) {
                server = ServerSocketChannel.open();
                server.configureBlocking(false);
                server.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(IpAddress, port));

                server.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

         }
           while (selector.isOpen()) {

               selector.select();

               Iterator iterator = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
              if (!iterator.hasNext()){Toast.makeText(cx, "iterrator is empty ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) iterator.next();
                if (key.isAcceptable()) {

                    SocketChannel client = server.accept();
                    if (client != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(cx, "New Image Recieved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //This Toas Doesn't Appear EVER
                        Socket socket = client.socket();
                        inRead = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
                        num = inRead.read();

                        Toast.makeText(cx, "New = " + num, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    }


                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Looper.prepare();

     Toast.makeText(cx,"Error" + e.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          } }}
```

My Client Program

```
   public class Client {

     public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
           String num=" ";
           Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
           try {
              Socket  s = new Socket("192.168.3.100",5050);
                while(true){
                  PrintStream p = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
                  System.out.println(p.toString());
                  num=sc.next();
                  p.println(num);
                 }

            }
             catch (Exception e ) {
                 System.out.println(e);}}}
```

Comment: Wait why is your server running inside your phone again?

Comment: Sorry i Don't understand ,the phone is carrying the Server Task ,and the Server code should be on my phone

Comment: `A simple Client/Server App` ??? Your code is not simple at all. If you have no experience in socket programming then you should start with ServerSocket and Socket classes.

Comment: @greenapps 
I have a PC and Android Phone ,I want The PC to send a number

Comment: @greenapps

the Task required from my program is very simple and it needs such code    and thats why i call it simple

Comment: the PC should send a number to the Phone                                                  please tell me if i am Naming The Question in a wrong way ,i will change it       but i think that is enough explanation of my problem isn't it ?

Comment: aha ,yes thank you for that ,i got it now

Comment: `nothing shows up in my android activity `. If the client could connect to te server and indeed the server had received something then your app would crash. Please put Log.d() statements in your server code and tell us which logs you see. Tell us how the code flows.

Comment: Have you implemented all of http://www.baeldung.com/java-nio-selector `http://www.baeldung.com/java-nio-selector` ? I feel there is missing a lot.

Comment: `Toast.makeText(cx, "iterrator is empty ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` If your server app does never crash then it never reaches the code where you display a Toast(). You cannot display a Toast() in the run() of a Thread(). Your app would crash then. You have several Toasts()'s.

Comment: In another application  i did the opposite, android is a client and pc is the server, everything went perfectly

Comment: the code flow reaches this **selector.isOpen()** and then gives me this         ........................................................................................            I/Choreographer: Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 39.959ms   @greenapps